# Invalid Markup Validation

Tags: html, validation

I am trying to validate my site (http://www.fsssouth.co.uk/) however, I get the following error(s). I am confused about this error specifically:

Line 569, Column 702: data-* attribute names must be XML 1.0 4th ed. plus Namespaces NCNames.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't allowed colons (`:`) in the names of `data-*` attributes.

Use another hyphen instead.

---

> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no uppercase ASCII letters.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

> Attribute names are said to be XML-compatible if they match the Name production defined in XML, **they contain no ":" (U+003A) characters**, and their first three characters are not an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string "xml". [XML]

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#xml-compatible

Comment: What should I use instead? data-iview( : )image

Comment: As I said in the answer: Use another hyphen instead. `data-iview-image`.

Comment: It doesn't work. The image is now not displayed. On the other hand, it does validate. What should I do now? Check it out for yourself at (http://www.fsssouth.co.uk/). Thank you for the help

Comment: You need to change whatever JavaScript you have that looks for `data-iview:image` to look for `data-iview-image` instead.